# Unused B1/2 2-year multiple entry visa

Tags: usa, b1-b2-visas

I got a two-year multiple entry visa on May 20, 2014 to attend a conference in California. Unfortunately for me, my company cancelled my leave because of an unexpected project we secured from Shell Nigeria.

Can I still use the same visa to visit the USA? I leave next month and I wish to visit the USA, but now I am thinking it might not be allowed.